# How to automate a FTP file transfer on Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, ftp

I'm trying to automate an FTP file transfer on linux to keep some backups on our intranet. My main problem is that I can't use SCP because SHH breaks our samba server and other stuff, so we are stuck with vsftp.

What I'm probably going to do, is create a bash to run in Cron every week. This is an example I found in the internet:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST='your.ftp.site'
USER='remoteusername'
PASSWD='remotepasswd'

ftp -n -v $HOST << EOT

   ascii
    user $USER $PASSWD
    prompt
   [COMMANDS GO HERE]
    bye
    EOT
```

But I can't really find what codes to use beyond that to transfer files between the two computers. Would it be a simple CAT?

I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: "SHH breaks our samba server and other stuff" — That is very strange.

Comment: "But I can't really find what codes to use beyond that to transfer files between the two computers. " — Your question doesn't seem to be about programming so much as it is about how to use the ftp utility. [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=how+to+upload+file+with+command+line+ftp+client&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=8a8qWoiSLqin8weHlK_oAg) finds [this](https://tecadmin.net/download-upload-files-using-ftp-command-line/).

Comment: Indeed it is. But my boss apparently already tried installing SHH and it fracked over the server for a good while before he restored it. So I can't touch SHH.

Comment: How do you connect to the server?

Comment: @123 — The command `ftp -n -v $HOST` connects to the server

Comment: I mean if your not ftping. Does it not already have ssh on it, what linux is it?

Comment: Are you looking for a list of commands available for an ftp client?

Comment: Remove `ascii` and look here... https://wpguru.co.uk/2014/04/how-to-use-ftp-from-the-linux-command-line/

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities:
First: use `lftp`. Of course you should read the fine manual, but as an example:

```
echo "mirror --reverse --delete" | lftp -u $username,$password $mysite
```

Or use expect:

```
spawn ftp mysite
expect "Login:"
send "username\r"
expect "ssword:"
send "S0m3ting\r"
expect "ftp>"
send "prompt\r"
expect "ftp>"
send "cd somewher\r"
expect "ftp>"
send "mget allfiles.*\r"
expect "ftp>"
send "mput loadsofotherfiles.*\r"
expect "ftp>"
send "bye\r"
```

(note: this will work as a first test, but you shouldn't run like this in production)

Also note that `man ftp` will give you a list of the `[COMMANDS` (that) `GO HERE]`.

As a side note: ssh and SAMBA should run fine on the same server. You might want to research a bit what goes wrong there.